# First character of a variable in a shell script to uppercase?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a shell script that starts unit tests for modules. I need the name of the module in all lowercase and with the first character uppercase. So far I have been doing it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -x                                                                                                                                                                          
# z.B. getbrowser                                                                                                                                                                     
strModuleToTest=$1

# g                                                                                                                                                                                   
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter=${strModuleToTest:0:1}
# etbrowser                                                                                                                                                                           
strModuleToTestUppercaseLastletters=${strModuleToTest:1}

# g -> G                                                                                                                                                                              
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/a/A}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/b/B}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/c/C}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/d/D}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/e/E}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/f/F}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/g/G}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/h/H}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/i/I}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/j/J}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/k/K}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/l/L}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/m/M}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/n/N}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/o/O}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/p/P}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/q/Q}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/r/R}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/s/S}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/t/T}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/u/U}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/v/V}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/w/W}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/x/X}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/y/Y}"
strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter="${strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter/z/Z}"

# Getbrowser
strModuleToTestUppercase=$strModuleToTestUppercaseFirstletter""$strModuleToTestUppercaseLastletters
```

What would be an easier way to set $strModuleToTestUppercase? I tried

```
strModuleToTestUppercase="${strModuleToTest[@]^}"
```

or

```
strModuleToTestUppercasesed="sed 's/\<./\u&/g' $strModuleToTest"
```

but without success.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If:

```
s=somemodule
```

**with bash v4+**

```
echo ${s^}
```

This should work with a bit older bash versions (from Glenn):

```
echo $(tr a-z A-Z <<< ${s:0:1})${s:1}")
```

**with zsh**

```
echo ${(C)s}
```

**with ash and coreutils**

```
echo $(echo $s | cut -c1 | tr a-z A-Z)$(echo $s | cut -c2-)
```

**with GNU sed**

```
echo $s | sed 's/./\U&/'
```

**with BSD sed**

```
echo $s | sed '
  h;
  y/quvwxzdermatoglyphicsbfjkn/QUVWXZDERMATOGLYPHICSBFJKN/;
  G;
  s/\(.\)[^\n]*\n.\(.*\)/\1\2/;
'
```

**with awk**

```
echo $s | awk '{ print toupper(substr($0, 1, 1)) substr($0, 2) }'
```

**with perl**

```
echo $s | perl -nE 'say ucfirst'
```

**with python**

```
echo $s | python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.readline().rstrip().capitalize()'
```

**with ruby**

```
echo $s | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.capitalize'
```

**Output in all cases**

```
Somemodule
```

Comment: +1 best answer. Another alternative: `"$(tr a-z A-Z <<< ${s:0:1})${s:1}"`

Comment: zsh as always is cryptically easiest

Comment: In `awk` - and bash with `${s:0:1}${s:1}`: ` substr(s,i,n)  substr(s,i)` where s=string, i=start, n=length. In `python`, `rstrip()` removes the whitespaces.

Comment: `tr a-z A-Z` does not work for æ ø å letters.

Comment: @AkselA: you can work around this by adding the specific letters to the list, e.g.: `tr 'a-zæøå' 'A-ZÆØÅ'`

Answer (score 10):

You could use

```
strModuleToTestUpper=`sed 's/\(.\)/\U\1/' <<< "$strModuleToTest"`
```

Explanation

- `\(.\)` matches a single character
- `\U\1` replaces that character with an uppercase version
- no `/g` means only the first match is processed.

Answer (score 2):

Is perl ok?

```
$ x=foobar
$ x=$(echo "$x" | perl -pe 's/^(.)/uc($1)/e')
$ echo $x
Foobar
```

Comment: `perl -ne 'print ucfirst'` would be simpler.

Comment: @chepner: or for 3 fewer characters `perl -pe '$_=ucfirst'`

Comment: @Thor or for 4 fewer characters `perl -pe \$_=ucfirst` :-)