# uppercase first character in a variable with bash

Tags: bash

I want to uppercase just the first character in my string with bash.

```
foo="bar";

//uppercase first character

echo $foo;
```

should print "Bar";

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but many of the techniques described in [Converting string to lower case in Bash shell scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2264428/4154375) can also be applied to this problem.

Comment: While this question is about Bash, Zsh users can look at [*First character of a variable in a shell script to uppercase?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420317/first-character-of-a-variable-in-a-shell-script-to-uppercase).

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
foo="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${foo:0:1})${foo:1}"
```

Comment: Despite being more complex than the best scored answer, this one actually does exactly that: 'uppercase first character in a variable'. Best scored answer does not have that results. Looks like simple answers are upvoted more willingly than the correct ones?

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński: Actually, the "best scored answer" below will produce the same results as this answer under Bash 4. This answer has the overhead of calling a subshell (another shell), the overhead of calling the 'tr' utility (another process, not Bash), the overhead of using a here-doc/string (temporary file creation) and it uses two substitutions compared to the best scored answer's one. If you absolutely must write legacy code, consider using a function instead of a subshell.

Comment: This answer assumes the input is all lower case. This variant has no assumptions: $(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${foo:0:1})$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< ${foo:1})

Comment: @ItaiHanski The OP did not specify what should happen to the remaining characters, only the first.  Supposed they wanted to change `notQuiteCamel` into `NotQuiteCamel`. Your variant has the side effect or forcing the remaining to lowercase - at the cost of doubling the number of sub shells and tr processes.

Comment: @JesseChisholm true - my script is not camel case friendly, but intentionally so.

Comment: Your are using a lot of bashism like `<<<` and string range, and this is not a good thing for portable scripts.

Comment: Works only on ASCII

Comment: @DanieleOrlando, true, but this question has no tags other than `bash`.

Comment: @Bell, that depends on whether your local platform's implementation of `tr` is multi-byte capable. The GNU one isn't, but BSD, Solaris and MacOS `tr` implementations are fine.

Comment: awsome!!，it work for me, otherwith when I use echo "${foo^}" on mac ,it always say bash: ${foo^}: bad substitution

Comment: The version of Bash shipped with Mac OS is pretty old, so that's why the Bash-only solution doesn't work there.

Answer (score 460):

One way with bash (version 4+):

```
foo=bar
echo "${foo^}"
```

prints:

```
Bar
```

Comment: Is there an opposite to this?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: To lowercase the first letter, use `"${foo,}"`. To lowercase all the letters, use `"${foo,,}"`. To uppercase all the letters, use `"${foo^^}"`.

Comment: @A-B-B: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but you'd likely need to assign another variable if you're trying to substring `foo`.

Comment: This only capitalizes the first letter of the first word on multi word string. Not a full solution.

Comment: I accidentally noticed that `${foo~}` and `${foo~~}` have the same effect as  `${foo^}` and `${foo^^}`. But I never saw that alternative mentioned anywhere.

Comment: How can I use the combination of , and ^ like if I want to smaller all the letters and then capitalise only the first one. Then it is not working `echo "${foo,,^}"`

Comment: @KNDheeraj: Best to use another variable for that, e.g.: `lc_foo="${foo,,}"; echo "${lc_foo^}"`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on Macs. getting the following error: `bad substitution`

Comment: @TolandHon: What's the output of `bash --version`?

Comment: @Steve GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)

Comment: @TolandHon: As you've probably already worked out, you'll need to upgrade to version 4.x, or try another solution if that machine can't be upgraded for some reason.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with stdin - ie echo hello | <what goes here>?

Comment: @nevster: Without putting stdin into a variable (which you probably don't want to do), you could use [tag:sed], [tag:awk] or [tag:perl]. E.g. `echo "hello world" | perl -ne 'print ucfirst'` prints `Hello world`.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same functionality on bash 3.2? @Michal's code works but is a bit too hacky.

Comment: @wlnirvana: Michael Hoffman's answer is the best to my knowledge when working under Bash 3. You could try compartmentalizing Michael's code in a function. That might make your code more readable. HTH.

Comment: @stephanmg: version 4+ just means version 4 or greater. I.e. it works with versions 4 and 5, but not version 3.

Comment: Okay,  then this does not work for my OSX bash which is version 4.3 or so.

Comment: @stephanmg: Is your default shell Zsh? `echo "${(C)foo}"`

Comment: @stephanmg: What is the error message you get? Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the behaviour? I suspect your interpreter is not actually BASH version 4 or Zsh.

Comment: @Steve I presume too. It is Bash provided by OSX, so there might be differences. RIght now I cannot provide the example. Sorry.

Comment: @TolandHon: I think you may not have this problem anymore, if the problem still presist, please try to run the bash filename.sh. this will solve the error "bad substitution"

Comment: Source: https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 43):

One way with `sed`:

```
echo "$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/.*/\u&/')"
```

Prints:

```
Bar
```

Comment: doesn't work on MacOS10 Lion sed, sigh, the \u expands to u instead of being an operator.

Comment: @vwvan `brew install coreutils gnu-sed` and follow the instructions to use the commands without the prefix `g`. For what it's worth I've never wanted to run the OSX version of these commands since getting the GNU versions.

Comment: @vwvan: Yes, sorry, you will need GNU `sed` in this instance

Comment: @Dean: FWIW, I've never wanted to run OSX :-)

Comment: Just change it to `sed 's/./\U&/` and it will work on POSIX sed.

Comment: `.*` will convert all letters, not just the first one.

Comment: @Martin `.*` will *match* all *characters*, but then `\u` will *convert* only the first character of the matched string.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24042315/812102) for a few more details.

Comment: @DavidConrad `echo "bar" | sed 's/./\U&/'` produces `Ubar` on mac. I think `\U` is not POSIX standard but a GNU extension.

Comment: @winirvana hmm, could be

Comment: Tested, this is the superior way for batch-processing newline-delimited files. Cheers!

Answer (score 34):

To capitalize first word only:

```
foo='one two three'
foo="${foo^}"
echo $foo
```

> **O**ne two three

---

To capitalize **every word** in the variable:

```
foo="one two three"
foo=( $foo ) # without quotes
foo="${foo[@]^}"
echo $foo
```

> **O**ne **T**wo **T**hree

---

(works in bash 4+)

Comment: `foo='one two three'; foo=$(for i in $foo; do echo -n "${i^} "; done)` 
Shorter resolution for every word. *foo* Now is "One Two Three"

Comment: How can I capitalize first 3 or 4 letters to uppercase ? Like **pqrs-123-v1** to **PQRS-123-v1** ? Or you can say, all letters before first hyphen...

Comment: This is simple and perfect.

Answer (score 29):

```
$ foo="bar";
$ foo=`echo ${foo:0:1} | tr  '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`${foo:1}
$ echo $foo
Bar
```

Answer (score 18):

Using awk only

```
foo="uNcapItalizedstrIng"
echo $foo | awk '{print toupper(substr($0,0,1))tolower(substr($0,2))}'
```

Comment: result: Uncapitalizedstring

Comment: looking at this one like ️️

Answer (score 16):

Here is the "native" text tools way:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="abcd"
first=`echo $string|cut -c1|tr [a-z] [A-Z]`
second=`echo $string|cut -c2-`
echo $first$second
```

Comment: finally something that works with a variable and on Mac! Thank you!

Comment: @DanieleOrlando, not as portable as one might hope. `tr [:lower:] [:upper:]` is a better choice if it needs to work in language/locales incorporating letters that aren't in the `a-z` or `A-Z` ranges.

Comment: Nice unix tool answer. Although yes what Charles said. In fact, in the man page of tr, it says: The example of `Translate the contents of file1 to upper-case.` is `tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" < file1` and that `(This should be preferred over the traditional UNIX idiom of “tr a-z A-Z”, since it works correctly in all locales.)`.

Answer (score 14):

just for fun here you are :

```
foo="bar";    

echo $foo | awk '{$1=toupper(substr($1,0,1))substr($1,2)}1'
# or
echo ${foo^}
# or
echo $foo | head -c 1 | tr [a-z] [A-Z]; echo $foo | tail -c +2
# or
echo ${foo:1} | sed -e 's/^./\B&/'
```

Comment: Thank you for, AFAICT, the _only_ solutions that don't involve GNUisms.

Comment: (Specifically, the `awk` solution works with any POSIX-compliant awk.)

Comment: This works on MacOS and with ZSH.

Comment: The fourth example only works for strings starting with the letter B. This does make it slightly less versatile than other answers on this page.

Answer (score 7):

It can be done in pure bash with bash-3.2 as well:

```
# First, get the first character.
fl=${foo:0:1}

# Safety check: it must be a letter :).
if [[ ${fl} == [a-z] ]]; then
    # Now, obtain its octal value using printf (builtin).
    ord=$(printf '%o' "'${fl}")

    # Fun fact: [a-z] maps onto 0141..0172. [A-Z] is 0101..0132.
    # We can use decimal '- 40' to get the expected result!
    ord=$(( ord - 40 ))

    # Finally, map the new value back to a character.
    fl=$(printf '%b' '\'${ord})
fi

echo "${fl}${foo:1}"
```

Comment: how to define foo? I tried `foo = $1` but I only get `-bash: foo: command not found`

Comment: @OZZIE, no spaces around the `=` in assignments. This is something that http://shellcheck.net/ will find for you programatically.

Comment: I always forget that about shell scripts.. only language where one space (before/after) matters... sigh (python is at least 4 if I remember correctly)

Comment: @OZZIE, it *has* to matter, because if it didn't matter, you couldn't pass `=` as an argument to a program (how is it supposed to know if `someprogram =` is running `someprogram`, or assigning to a variable named `someprogram`?)

Answer (score 7):

This works too...

```
FooBar=baz

echo ${FooBar^^${FooBar:0:1}}

=> Baz
```

```
FooBar=baz

echo ${FooBar^^${FooBar:1:1}}

=> bAz
```

```
FooBar=baz

echo ${FooBar^^${FooBar:2:2}}

=> baZ
```

And so on.

Sources:

- Bash Manual: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- Full Bash Guide: [Parameters](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#Parameters)
- Bash Hacker's Wiki [Parameter Expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe?s[]=length)

Inroductions/Tutorials:

- Cyberciti.biz: [8. Convert to upper to lower case or vice versa](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html)
- Opensource.com: [An introduction to parameter expansion in Bash](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/bash-parameter-expansion)

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

Searching for all *php file in the current directory , and replace the first character of each filename to capital letter:

e.g:  test.php  =>  Test.php

```
for f in *php ; do mv "$f" "$(\sed 's/.*/\u&/' <<< "$f")" ; done
```

Comment: The original question was a string, and made no reference to renaming files.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative and clean solution for both Linux and OSX, it can also be used with bash variables

```sh
python -c "print(\"abc\".capitalize())"
```

returns Abc

Answer (score 0):

This is POSIX sh-compatible as far as I know.

upper_first.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "$1" | cut -c1 -z | tr -d '\0' | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
printf "$1" | cut -c2-
```

`cut -c1 -z` ends the first string with `\0` instead of `\n`.  It gets removed with `tr -d '\0'`.  It also works to omit the `-z` and use `tr -d '\n'` instead, but this breaks if the first character of the string is a newline.

Usage:

```
$ upper_first.sh foo
Foo
$
```

In a function:

```
#!/bin/sh

function upper_first ()
{
    printf "$1" | cut -c1 -z | tr -d '\0' | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
    printf "$1" | cut -c2-
}

old="foo"
new="$(upper_first "$old")"
echo "$new"
```

Answer (score 0):

Posix compliant and with less sub-processes:

```
v="foo[Bar]"
printf "%s" "${v%"${v#?}"}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' && printf "%s" "${v#?}"
==> Foo[Bar]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
first-letter-to-lower () {
        str="" 
        space=" " 
        for i in $@
        do
                if [ -z $(echo $i | grep "the\|of\|with" ) ]
                then
                        str=$str"$(echo ${i:0:1} | tr  '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')${i:1}$space" 
                else
                        str=$str${i}$space 
                fi
        done
        echo $str
}
first-letter-to-upper-xc () {
        v-first-letter-to-upper | xclip -selection clipboard
}
first-letter-to-upper () {
        str="" 
        space=" " 
        for i in $@
        do
                if [ -z $(echo $i | grep "the\|of\|with" ) ]
                then
                        str=$str"$(echo ${i:0:1} | tr  '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')${i:1}$space" 
                else
                        str=$str${i}$space 
                fi
        done
        echo $str
}
```

first-letter-to-lower-xc(){
        v-first-letter-to-lower | xclip -selection clipboard
    }

Answer (score -4):

Not exactly what asked but quite helpful

```
declare -u foo #When the variable is assigned a value, all lower-case characters are converted to upper-case.

foo=bar
echo $foo
BAR
```

And the opposite

```
declare -l foo #When the variable is assigned a value, all upper-case characters are converted to lower-case.

foo=BAR
echo $foo
bar
```

Answer (score -7):

What if the first character **is not** a letter (but a tab, a space, and a escaped double quote)? We'd better **test** it **until** we find a letter! So:

```
S='  \"ó foo bar\"'
N=0
until [[ ${S:$N:1} =~ [[:alpha:]] ]]; do N=$[$N+1]; done
#F=`echo ${S:$N:1} | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`
#F=`echo ${S:$N:1} | sed -E -e 's/./\u&/'` #other option
F=`echo ${S:$N:1}
F=`echo ${F} #pure Bash solution to "upper"
echo "$F"${S:(($N+1))} #without garbage
echo '='${S:0:(($N))}"$F"${S:(($N+1))}'=' #garbage preserved

Foo bar
= \"Foo bar=
```

Comment: Please write cleaner code! you're lacking quotes _all over the place._ You're using obsolete syntax (backticks); you're using antiquated syntax (`$[...]`). You're using lots of useless parentheses. You're assuming that the string consists of characters from the latin alphabet (how about accentuated letters, or letters in other alphabets?). You have a great deal of work to render this snippet usable! (and since you're using regex, you might as well use the regex to find the first letter, instead of a loop).

Comment: I think you're wrong. It's the obligatory comment that accompanies the downvote, explaining all the wrong patterns and misconceptions of the answer. Please, learn from your mistakes (and before that, try to understand them) instead of being stubborn. Being a good fellow is also incompatible with spreading bad practices.

Comment: Better written as: `if [[ $S =~ ^([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]])(.*) ]]; then out=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$(tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' <<<"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")${BASH_REMATCH[3]}; else out=$S; fi; printf '%s\n' "$out"`

Comment: Or, if using Bash ≥4, you don't need `tr`: `if [[ $S =~ ^([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]].*) ]]; then out=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]^}; else out=$S; fi; printf '%s\n' "$out"`

Comment: More light on the subject: "when "binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, **it's perfectly safe to leave variable expansions unquoted** on the left-hand side, but you need to know that variable expansions will happen on the right-hand side." http://stackoverflow.com/a/18710850/559742

Comment: This code is still badly broken. It's still using backticks instead of modern substitution syntax; it still has unmatched quotes; it still has missing quotes *in places where they do in fact matter*; etc. Try putting some whitespace-surrounded glob characters into your test data, if you don't believe that those missing quotes make a difference, and fix the issues http://shellcheck.net/ finds until this code comes up clean.

Comment: As for the language you quoted from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748, what you miss is that `echo $foo` is an example of a situation where **the parser expects a list of words**; so in your `echo ${F}`, the contents of `F` are string-split and glob-expanded. That's similarly true for the `echo ${S:$N:1}` example and all the rest. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: (It's also still using deprecated syntax. `N=$[$N+1]` isn't just a stylistic choice without any functional impact: It's actually **less portable** than the POSIX-standardized `N=$((N+1))` syntax that replaces it, as it's a holdout from 1970s-era Bourne that wasn't added to the 1990s-era POSIX standard and is not guaranteed to be present in modern-day POSIX-based shells).