# linux how to change a file name to the name of its folder?

Tags: linux

I'm working in Linux,
I have a folder that contains many sub-folders, in each sub-folder there is a file named Analyze.txt.
I would like to move all these files (Analyze.txt) into one folder and change the name of the file Analyze.txt to the name of the sub-folder it originated from.

Thanks,

Raz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bash script .sh and give it the right permission

```
chmod +x <file>.sh
```

Let see the code to write into the script.
First of all move to the root directory:

```
cd <path-to-root>
```

Now you need to loop each sub-folder, rename the file in and then move it to destination directory:

```
for dir in `ls`; do
    if [[ -d $dir ]]; then
        cd $dir
        mv ./Analyze.txt ./$dir.txt
        mv ./$dir.txt <path-to-dest-directory>
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

With this code i supposed that the destination directory is not in the root of your tree.

Comment: is it possible to manipulate $dir to include only a part of the folder name? something like if $dir = ^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9h]*-[0-9m]*-[0-9s]*_(.*); then $name = $1 # (.*) ?

Comment: Yes you can use regex. Check out this answer: [Bash regex if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709962/bash-regex-if-statement) @xbarvazx