# Regex for capturing Curl HTTP Status Code and body response

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm attempting to create a regex that captures both the HTTP status code as well as the body of a curl request. The regex pattern below works on multiple online sites, but won't match [in a shell if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709962/bash-regex-if-statement) on my Mac's command line. Is my regex off or is there something else going on?

```
RESPONSE=$(curl -s -i -X GET http://www.google.com/)

# Match and capture the status code, match the headers, match two new lines, match and capture an optional body
re="^HTTP\/\d\.\d\s([\d]{3})[\w\d\s\W\D\S]*[\r\n]{2}([\w\d\s\W\D\S]*)?$"

if [[ "${RESPONSE}" =~ $re ]]; then
  echo "match"
  # Now do stuff with the captured groups, "${BASH_REMATCH[...]}"
else
  echo "no match"
fi
```

I'm also open to other ways of doing this (I'm targeting a machine running CentOS 5).

Comment: Write the body to a file and use the `-w` curl flag to have curl output just the status code to stdout?

Comment: Try using a basic regular expression like: `^HTTP/[0-9]\.[0-9] [0-9]{3} OK` Escaping periods and spaces is ok, but the other escape sequences are being interpreted literally. Don't think capturing the status code will work either. Might be better off with sed, awk, perl, etc.

Comment: @ColeTierney can you expand on that? Why would the other escape sequences such as `\d` or `\w` be interpreted literally?

Comment: @EtanReisner that's how I currently do it, though I'm trying to give myself a scenario where I don't have write access to the system, thus this question

Comment: I'm testing with bash 3.2.57(1)-release. Try the following 3 tests: `[[ " " =~ \s ]] && echo yes || echo no` (I get no), `[[ "\s" =~ \s  ]] && echo yes || echo no` (I get yes), and `[[ " " =~ [[:blank:]] ]] && echo yes || echo no` (I get yes).

Comment: @ColeTierney I get the same - I have the exact same version of Bash (which make sense if we both have fully-updated Macs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are open to other solutions, too, you can try this out.

```
RESPONSE=$(curl -s -i -X GET http://www.google.com/)

HTTP_STATUS_CODE=`echo $RESPONSE | sed '
  /HTTP/ { 
    s/^HTTP[^ ]* //
    s/ .*$//
    q
  }
  D'`

BODY=`echo $RESPONSE | sed '
  /^.$/ {
    :body
    n
    b body
  }
  D'`

echo $HTTP_STATUS_CODE
echo $BODY
```

`HTTP_STATUS_CODE` is found in the first line starting with HTTP. Every non-space until the first space is removed and from the result ('302 Found') everything from first space till the end of the line is removed.

`BODY` starts at the first line matching a single char (lines before are deleted with 'D'). From here print every line until the end of the input.

Comment: I like the idea, though both parts are giving `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` in my OSX terminal.

Comment: It works in my zsh and bash in OSX. I have no idea what the problem could be... I suggest to copy it to a text editor and show all non-printable chars.

Comment: I got the error fixed using the post linked by @neric in his answer. When running the above (with the fix, setting `LC_ALL=C` before each `sed`), the `HTTP_STATUS_CODE` comes through but the `BODY` seems to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as @delarsschneider, slightly less complicated

```
RESPONSE=$(curl -s -i -X GET http://www.google.com/)

CODE=$(echo $RESPONSE | sed -n 's/HTTP.* \(.*\) .*/\1/p')

BODY=$(echo $RESPONSE | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -n 's/.*GMT *\(.*\)/\1/p')

echo $CODE
echo $BODY
```

Comment: Exact same error as below: `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`. No idea why. I'm literally copy/pasting the above into terminal.

Comment: Hmm, did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Interesting. Putting `LC_ALL=C` before the `sed` for the `CODE` lets the command work but the output is wrong. `LC_ALL=C` before `sed` for the BODY the command still fails with the same error.

Comment: Alright, by using `export LC_CTYPE=C 
export LANG=C` I get both commands to work. Contents of `BODY` is correct, but contents of `CODE` is not. Seems to contain some random JS instead of the HTTP Status Code