# Bash script if -eq

Tags: bash, if-statement, equals

New to bash script, i need to check if the first word in Group equals the second word in Users.

```
Group=`echo $rules | egrep -v 'Test'`
Users=`echo $rules | grep -i 'Test' | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$2))}'`

if [ '$Group' -eq '$Users' ];
then
echo $Group
echo $Users

else
:
fi
```

Can I use something like this or how is this possible?

```
if [ '$Group $1' -eq '$Users $2' ];
```

or

```
if [ '^$Group' -eq '^$Users' ];
```

Comment: can you provide some sample input to play with? Also, I guess you need double quotes to have the values expanded --> `if [ "$Group" -eq "$Users" ]`.

Answer (score 4):

The operator `-eq` is used for integer comparison.
If you want to compare strings you must use `=` like this:

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

which is equivalent to

```
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
```

but NOT equivalent to (note the spaces)

```
if [ "$a"="$b" ]
```

However, if you want to use a regular expression (you used ^ which isn't a glob pattern wildcard) in a if statement look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709962/bash-regex-if-statement)

That said you should do the splitting before the if statement and put Users and Groups in two arrays.