# Grep: Regex for IP doesnt match

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ip

I was trying to create a regex that match a ip adress, or a ip adress with netmask:
something like 8.8.8.8/24

```
if ! [[ $SOURCE =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]] || [[ $SOURCE =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}$ ]];then
                echo ERROR: Invalid Source
                exit 1
fi
```

The first part matchted well, the second, with the netmask doest match..
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the regexps in separate variables and use a single pattern:

```
SOURCE="8.8.8.8"
RX="^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(/[0-9]{1,2})?$"
if ! [[ $SOURCE =~ $RX ]];then
                echo ERROR: Invalid Source
                exit 1
fi
```

See the [online demo here](https://ideone.com/1umTGQ).

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{1,3}\.` - 1 to 3 digits followed with a literal dot
- `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.` - same as above, 2 times
- `[0-9]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits (this matches the IP string)
- `(/[0-9]{1,2})?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences) sequence of:

  - `/` - a slash (since it is not a special char, it needs no escaping)
  - `[0-9]{1,2}`  - 1 to 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: RX1="^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$"
RX2="^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(/[0-9]{1,2})?$"
        if ! [[ $SOURCE1 =~ $RX1 ]] || [[ $SOURCE =~ $RX2 ]];then
                echo ERROR: Invalid Source
                exit 1
        fi

Comment: You do not need to use 2 regexps for this check, use one.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: Note that placing the pattern into a variable is the safest way of passing a regex inside `[[...]]`, as inside the RHS, variable expansion can occur. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18710850/3832970).