# Bash shell expansion gives command not found

Tags: bash, shell, command, pipe, expansion

I am pretty new to bash scripting I am amazed at everything it can do. I have hit a wall, tried a number of different combinations to get this to work and cannot seem to get it.

Any ideas / tips / answers would be greatly appreciated!

The problem: I have a file that gets dropped as part of an ldapsearch script, it contains sAMAccountName and mail attributes. These are on separate lines, I would like to:
1) take a grepped file (grep -E "sAMAccountName|mail") this produces one entry per line and output this as , which i will then feed to postmap hash:/etc/postfix/canonical  (ftw).

however! my plans for world domination have been delayed because the statement where i am assigning the output of the command execution to $stuff issues command not found... grrr. Please kind internet bash gurus point out my mistakes please! *note* not all the code is included, just the piece that is giving me trouble:
ref1: [Bash regex if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709962/bash-regex-if-statement)

```
#############################
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do

if [[ $line =~ ^sAM ]]; then
 stuff = $( echo "$line" | cut -d\: -f2) #<-- command not found
 echo -n $stuff >> /etc/postfix/tmp-canonical

fi

if [[ $line =~ ^mail ]]; then
 stuff = $( echo "$line" | cut -d\: -f2) #<-- command not found
 echo -n "<tab>$stuff\n" >> /etc/postfix/tmp-canonical

fi

done < "$1"
#end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stuff is interpreted as a command instead of variable assignment because of the space before the equal sign. Remove the space and it should work.

```
stuff=$( echo "$line" | cut -d\: -f2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help! I saw your answer appear as I was posting mine :) silly spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT! I just hadn't tried hard enough! Okay here is how i fixed it:

code snippet (the corrected)

```
STUFF=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\: -f2)
```

The original -

```
STUFF = $(echo "$line" | cut -d\: -f2)
```

The space between STUFF and the "=" was being interpreted, found this article: [How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)