# compare regex with grep output - bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to find the word "PASS_MAX_DAYS" in a file using grep
`grep "^PASS_MAX_DAYS" /etc/login.defs`
then I save it in a variable and compare it to a regular expression that has the value 90 or less.

`regex = "PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)"`

grep output is: PASS_MAX_DAYS 120

so my function should print a fail, however it matches:

```
function audit_Control () {

    if [[ $cmd =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo match
    else
        echo fail
    fi
}
cmd=`grep "^PASS_MAX_DAYS" /etc/login.defs`
regex="PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)"
audit_Control "$cmd" "$regex"
```

Comment: It appears bash `=~` regex doesn't support the common escapes like `\s` (`\\s`?) -- try `PASS_MAX_DAYS[[:space:]]*( etc )` instead. You might also want to add anchors `^PASS_MAX...(...)$` to make sure it's a whole-line match.

Comment: Sthephen You are the best, now it works correctly. Thank you!!!

Comment: made it an answer, if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the bash test `[[` using the regex match operator `=~` does not support the common escapes such as `\s` for whitespace or `\W` for non-word-characters.

It *does* support posix predefined [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), so you can use `[[:space:]]` in place of `\s`

Your regex would then be:
`regex="PASS_MAX_DAYS[[:space:]]*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)"`

You may want to add anchors `^` and `$` to ensure a whole-line match, then the regex is
`regex="^PASS_MAX_DAYS[[:space:]]*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)$"`

Without the end-of-line anchor you could match lines that have trailing numbers *after* the match, so `PASS_MAX_DAYS 9077` would match `PASS_MAX_DAYS 90` and the trailing "77" would not prevent the match.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710850/17300) also has some very useful information about bash's `[[ ]]` construction with the `=~` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a problem with your regex, please try that version:

`PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)$`

```
[lucas@lucasmachine ~]$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

function audit_Control () {

    if [[ $cmd =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo match
    else
        echo fail
    fi
}
regex="PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)$"
audit_Control "$cmd" "$regex"
[lucas@lucasmachine ~]$ export cmd="PASS_MAX_DAYS 123"
[lucas@lucasmachine ~]$ ./test.sh 
fail
[lucas@lucasmachine ~]$ export cmd="PASS_MAX_DAYS 1"
[lucas@lucasmachine ~]$ ./test.sh 
match
```

I can explain the problem was the other regex was not checking the end of line, so, your were matching "PASS_MAX_DAYS 1"23 so 23 were not being "counted" to your regex. Your regex was really matching part of the text.. Now with the end of line it should match exactly 1 digit find a end of line, or [1-8][0-9] end of line or 90 end of line.