# Name check match pattern

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need help as to why code B is producing a different result

```
x=TEST_DATA_12345678_TST_87456321
```

The code below (CODE A) produces the correct output (match)

```
if [[ $x == TEST_[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "non match"; fi
```

However, the below  (CODE B) produces a wrong output (no match)

```
if [[ $x == TEST_[A-Z]{4}_[0-9]{8}_[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{8} ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "non match"; fi
```

Comment: Using `==` means its a match using shell globbing. To use regex matching, use `=~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check [a regex in an if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709962/regex-matching-in-a-bash-if-statement) you'll need to use `=~` instead off `==`;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

x=TEST_DATA_12345678_TST_87456321
if [[ $x =~ TEST_[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "non match"; fi
if [[ $x =~ TEST_[A-Z]{4}_[0-9]{8}_[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{8} ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "non match"; fi
```

Both will match as expected.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8I2xDU4JN7FMcQx3tDI2MTUzNwiPgQoYmEOZBsbGXJlpilERyuoVCjY1imA1UY76kbFohHx0Qa6lrFEEPHkalSIjbVWKMlIzVNITc7IV1DKTSxJzlCyVkjNKU6FCuXl5ynAhNMycTi82qQWYme1RS1UxBghQrIt//8DAA)

Comment: Note that glob matches (with `=` or `==`) must match the entire string; by default, regex matches only need to match *part of* the string. To force whole-string matching, add anchors: `^` at the beginning, and `$` at the end.